# Dart Error : Class '_Template' has no instance method 'render' with matching arguments

Tags: templates, dart, mustache

When the below chunk of DART program is executed, error "Breaking on exception: Class '_Template' has no instance method 'render' with matching arguments." is thrown.

```
var source = '{{#data}}<div>{{title}},{{time}}</div>{{/data}}';
var template = mustache.parse(source);
var output;
output = template.render({'guide_data_cell': [{'title': 'friends','time': '10:00 PM'}]});
```

Please help if I missed any syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the `package:mustache` docs, `render()` requires both a values map and a StringSink, or you can use `renderString()` which only requires a values map.

If you're using the Dart Editor, it should show a warning on the call to `render()` for the mismatched arguments.